# Selected index for multiple listboxes

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program that requires a user to enter information for either their house or apartment.  They will enter information on property id, address, year build, bedrooms, square footage, and price. Once they've done that they choose to either enter yes or no for "furnished"(this applies to apartment) or they can enter a number for garage capacity(this applies to house).  I have a method called DisplayInfo() that shows all this information in a column.  The program has two listboxes at the bottom, one for apartment and one for house.  There are also two buttons, one for add house and one for add apartment.  This button will add the address to the respective listbox.  The problem i'm having is that on the final button called display, the selected house or apartment should be shown in a messagebox that shows all the information using DisplayInfo().  this is what i have right now

this is the DisplayInfo() method

```
        public virtual string DisplayInfo()
    {
        return string.Format("Property ID: {0}\nProperty Address: {1}\nYear Built: {2}\nNumber of Bedrooms: {3}\nSquare Footage: {4}\nPrice: {5}", GetID(),
            GetAddress(), GetYearBuilt(), GetBedrooms(), GetSquareFootage(), GetPrice());
```

this is what i have for displaying the messagebox and all it does is display each house or apartment input by the user in different messageboxes.

```
         foreach (Property_Dwelling property in Home)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(property.DisplayInfo(), property.GetType().ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

and

```
        foreach (Property_Dwelling property in Home)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(property.DisplayInfo(), property.GetType().ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Comment: so the problem is?? also the last two body of code are the same...

Comment: the problem is that the second and third code snippet above are for the display house and display apartment buttons.  I need to have them display just the information for the selected address.  Instead, the code above shows all the inputed houses or apartments in multiple messageboxes regardless of the selected index

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: New code, based on the comments**

```
foreach (Property_Dwelling property in Home)
{
    //Only displays the messagebox if the address of the property is the same as the text displayed in the listbox
    if(property.GetAddress() == myListBox.Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(property.DisplayInfo(), property.GetType().ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

You may want to verify if an item is selected before trying to display its information though.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thats the problem though.  My DisplayInfo() method isn't an option.  It just gives me an error and is says DisplayInfo() doesn't exist in this context.

Comment: What did you put in your listbox? A list of IDs as strings or something?

Comment: I have it set up that when someone adds a home or apartment the address goes to the respective listbox.  Then, the user can select the address and click the "show" button that should show all the properties from the arraylist

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was drawing a blank on trying to verify it!

Answer (score 0):

So, you are showing all the homes, because you are doing a for each around home (is that a class?) and that is showing all the info.

You should first locate the item you want to display inside home, and then only show it data.

Comment: all this info should be in the main post. the ArrayList of what? of Property_Dwelling that is a class?